# Why this lucene query string is wrong?

Tags: lucene

Well when I want to do some query on my lucene index, I found a problem:

```
+(title:a^4.0) +((+type:restaurant +city:CA)  (-type:restaurant))
```

I just want to restrict results that city `is not CA` and `type is restaurant`.

But lucene give me a result just that:

```
 +(+type:restaurant +city:CA) and ignore (-type:restaurant )
```

Can you tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I do not get exactly what you want, you are probably asking about Boolean Lucene query syntax. I believe [Hossman's blog post about Boolean queries](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2011/12/28/why-not-and-or-and-not/) may help you.